# How to convert a termDocumentMatrix which I have got from text mining in R into excel or CSV file?

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining

To be more more specific. Lets say I have a character vector "names" with the following elements:

```
Names[1]<-"aaron, matt, patrick",
Names[2]<-"jiah, ron, melissa, john, patrick"
```

and so on......I have 22956 elements like this. I want to separate all the names and assign them a separate column in excel.
How do I do this? It requires text mining. But I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a list of strings elements separated by a comma, with different number of elements.

```
Names <- c("aaron, matt, patrick",
           "jiah, ron, melissa, john, patrick")

## get max number of elements
mm <-  mm <- max(unlist(lapply(strsplit(Names,','),length)))
## set all rows the same length
lapply(strsplit(Names,','),function(x) {length(x) <- mm;x})
## create a data frame with the data welle formatted
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(Names,','),function(x) {length(x) <- mm;x}))
## save the file
write.csv(res,'output.csv')
```

I think also you can use `rbind.fill` from plyr package, but you have to coerce each row to a `data.frame`( certain cost).

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I have one more doubt. I have generated a Term Document Matrix using TermDocumentMatrix() function in R. How do I convert it into data frame or write it into csv file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the TDM does what you need, you should be able to coerce the TDM object into a matrix using the `as.matrix` function and then export to csv as usual.

```
tdmMatrix <- as.matrix(myTDM)
write.csv(tdmMatrix, 'myfile.csv')
```