# R - How do I stop a data frame printing itself to the console

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and am working on a text mining project.  I have all the analysis working however when I convert the Term-Document Matrix back to a data frame it fills the console with the content..

The code I'm using for this is:

```
TDM.frame <- data.frame(inspect(Words.TDM))
```

The frame has 9k objects in it so I won't paste that here too but you can imagine what the console looks like when it dumps the whole content out ^^

I've tried using invisible() but that doesn't change anything.  I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or offer a solution!

Thanks!

Comment: `inspect()` seems to be from the tm package. But is this maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981599/how-to-convert-a-termdocumentmatrix-which-i-have-got-from-text-mining-in-r-into since it is practically asking for the same thing?

Comment: @Khl4v: It did turn out to be a duplicate in terms of needed function, but it had the additional aspect of not understanding reason for the extra output to the console. Upvoted your answer which was also what one of the respondents to your cited question offered, but I'm not voting to close.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I didn't realise that was what I was actually asking *blush*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `inspect` does (at least in the case where it is given a TDM):

```
> tm:::inspect.TermDocumentMatrix
function (x) 
{
    print(x)
    cat("\n")
    print(as.matrix(x))
}
<environment: namespace:tm>
```

So you want the object that is returned which is just `as.matrix(tdm)` and you do not want the printing side-effect. So you should just do this instead:

```
 TDM.frame <- data.frame(as.matrix(Words.TDM))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the `inspect()` within `data.frame()` really necessary? Can you perhaps just convert the TDM to a matrix, since it seems this is what you are trying to achieve? If necessary, you can then convert the matrix to a data frame.

```
as.matrix(Words.TDM)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem :D And is what I should have done from the start!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TDM.frame <- data.frame(inspect(Words.TDM))
head(TDM.frame)
```

Or, you can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
TDM.frame <- tbl_df(TDM.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! woulc TDM.frame <- tbl_df(TDM.frame) work, since the original data is in a TDM, not a frame?   If I apply the Words.TDM variable to it it errors.  

head(TDM.frame <- data.frame(inspect(Words.TDM)))  dumps the whole thing still and then gives the header summary at the end :(

Comment: Check my edited answer, you don't need to wrap the whole thing with head.